# framework not found Xcode 7.1

Tags: xcode7.1

I opened my old project in Xcode 7.1 and I encountered an error.

```
ld: framework not found LibXL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

- I had the framework `LibXL` in the project folder.
- `Always search user path` is set to `YES`. //Tried with `NO`
- `Framework Search Path` is set to the framework path `$(PROJECT_DIR)` which is `/Users/Mr.T/Desktop/Project`.   //Tried with `recursive` and `non-recursive`

  More information:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not sure about the `run path search path`, and what value it should contain!!!

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Build Settings` and add `$(PROJECT_DIR)` non-recursive to `Framework Search Paths`

There is no need to change `Runpath Search Paths`

Answer (score 0):

The framework got updated by LibXL and somehow the old framework is not recognised by the Xcode. I downloaded the framework again, and add it to the project!!! It worked now!!!